# Powershell replace in file using regex

Tags: regex, file, powershell, replace, gpo

Good afternoon, I am looking to modify a preference file to reset the default zoom in chrome with a powershell script that will later be deployed by gpo.

The strategy is to remove a portion of the setting that is responsible for the default zoom. It works perfectly when it's done by hand. However, with this script, I get a message that the preference file is bad.

Code:

```
#Déclarations
$preferencePath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE                      'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences'
$newPreferencePath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE   'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\newpref.txt'
$regex = '("default_zoom_level":)[^\s]\d*.\d*(":)\d*.\d*(},)'

#Créer la version corrigé du fichier de préférence
Get-Content -path $preferencePath | % { $_ -Replace $regex , '' }  |  Out-    File $newPreferencePath

#Renomme les fichiers pour que le bon soit pris en compte
Rename-Item $preferencePath "PreferencesBAK"
Rename-Item $newPreferencePath "Preferences"
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with that code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the replace function. Also, encoding is ASCII. Here is the working code for those that are interested:

```
#Déclarations
$preferencePath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences'
$newPreferencePath = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\newpref.txt'
$oldPrefFile = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE 'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\PreferencesBAK'
$regex = '("default_zoom_level":)[^\s]\d*.\d*(":)\d*.\d*(},)'

#Créer la version corrigé du fichier de préférence
Get-Content -path $preferencePath | % { $_ -Replace $regex , ' ' } |  Out-File -Encoding ASCII $newPreferencePath

#Renomme les fichiers pour que le bon soit pris en compte
if (Test-Path $oldPrefFile) {
   Remove-Item $oldPrefFile
}
Rename-Item $preferencePath "PreferencesBAK"
Rename-Item $newPreferencePath "Preferences"
```

Comment: I see you haven't done it yet, just wanted to let you know that you can click the grey check mark to accept your own answer, that way it stands out better to the community.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `Out-File` defaults to UTF-16LE as the file encoding. Most likely you need to write it as UTF-8 instead (check the encoding of the file beforehand):

```
... | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $newPreferencePath
```